# Why my app-template is not taking effect on all its children in XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<page>
   <link name="Index">index.jsp</link>
   <link name="Welcome">welcome.jsp</link>
</page>
```

I am using the following xsl file to produce a html file:

```
....
<xsl:template match="/page/link" >
   <a href="{/page/link}" > <xsl:value-of select="@name" /> </a>
</xsl:template >
```

However, the both links are taking the value of the first child element as the reference, hence both links take the user to index.jsp

could you guys give me some advices as I am new to XSLT. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using an absolute path in your AVT, which will result in the first value matched. Instead, do this:

```
<xsl:template match="/page/link" >
   <a href="{.}" > <xsl:value-of select="@name" /> </a>
</xsl:template >
```

Answer (score 2):

JLRishe has given you the answer, I will try giving the advice!

When you write XSLT code, always be aware of the context. XPath expressions select relative to the context. Within a template rule with match="/page/link", the context item is a "link" element. When the context item is a link element, /page/link goes up to the root of the tree (because of the initial "/") and then selects all the page children, and then selects all their link children. Which gives you all the links.

In XSLT 1.0 (which you appear to be using) an attribute value template such as `{/page/link}` will display the first link. In XSLT 2.0 it will display all the selected links, space-separated. Neither is what you want.